# Angular async not resolving timeouts

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

It looks like Angular's `async` from `@angular/core/testing` isn't resolving timeouts in tests with `async` when there's a beforeEach with `async` as well. 
 Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce this bug on any kind of Plunkr or JSFiddle.

The easiest way to recreate it is to simple create a fresh new Angular CLI app and paste this code into the app.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async } from "@angular/core/testing";

describe("test async", () => {

   let count: number = 0;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
       count++;
       console.log('async before test ' + count);
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('timeout before test ' + count);
       }, 1000);
   }))

   it("async test 1", async(() => {
       console.log('starting test 1');
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('test 1 finished');
           console.log('expected count: 1, actual count: ' + count);
           expect(count).toBe(1, "should be test 1");
       }, 2000);
   }));

   it("async test 2", async(() => {
       console.log('starting test 2');
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('test 2 finished');
           console.log('expected count: 2, actual count: ' + count);
           expect(count).toBe(2, "should be test 2");
       }, 2000);
   }));

   it("async test 3", async(() => {
       console.log('starting test 3');
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('test 3 finished');
           console.log('expected count: 3, actual count: ' + count);
           expect(count).toBe(3, "should be test 3");
       }, 2000);
   }));
});
```

If you then run this test, you should see the output as follows:

```
async before test 1
timeout before test 1
starting test 1
async before test 2
timeout before test 2
starting test 2
async before test 3
test 1 finished
expected count: 1, actual count: 3
timeout before test 3
starting test 3
test 2 finished
expected count: 2, actual count: 3
test 3 finished
expected count: 3, actual count: 3
```

But that is incorrect from my understanding because the timeouts in the tests should complete before the next test starts, which is the whole point of async.

This is what the output would look like if it was working correctly:

```
async before test 1
timeout before test 1
starting test 1
test 1 finished
expected count: 1, actual count: 1
async before test 2
timeout before test 2
starting test 2
test 2 finished
expected count: 2, actual count: 2
async before test 3
timeout before test 3
starting test 3
test 3 finished
expected count: 3, actual count: 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of writing this, it's a bug with Angular.  I've found 2 tickets confirming this: [#16647](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16647) and [#12115](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12115)

Answer (score -3):

> async from @angular/core/testing isn't resolving timeouts in tests with async when there's a beforeEach with async as well

`async` only resolves Promises not `setTimeout`. You can wrap setTimeout in a delay function

```
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,ms));
```

Comment: `async` still works on the specs if the `beforeEach` doesn't have `async` though.

Do you have any documentation to show that `async` doesn't work with `setTimeout`?

Comment: You've provided no documentation to support that `async` only resolves Promises and not `setTimeout`, which is factually incorrect and you linked to your own material that talks about that without disclosing your affiliation.  I'm reporting this answer for spam.

Comment: This answer is also factually incorrect.  Nowhere in Angular docs does it say that `async` doesn't work with `setTimeout`.  In fact, one of the issues I linked shows someone doing just that.  Additionally, when using `async` on a spec without `beforeEach` it works completely as expected.